# Best practice for generating refresh token with JWT

Tags: authentication, jwt, refresh-token

### Background

I'm implementing an authentication system based on JWT and Refresh tokens but I had an hard time searching for serious documentation about the refresh token generation and handling.
The common scenarios I've found expect:

- A short-live token JWT that is stateless and not stored on the server-side
- A long-live refresh token that is stored somewhere on the client side and on the server-side and that allows to get new authorized JWTs.

### Refresh token generation

My first question is about the refresh token generation. I've seen two main scenarios:

- The refresh token is a simple random string or a uuid that it is stored (with its expiring time) on the server side and represent a long user session
- The refresh token is itself a JWT containing the not-sensitive data of the user that has logged in and has itself an expiration

The first case is the simplest but allows to encapsulate session data only manually, the second case is more complex but allows to encapsulate the session data, the expiration and it is generated only by a secret held in the server (it means more security). In this last case, however, making the JWT persistent is against the JWT phylosophy and more effort is required for validating also this JWT and comparing the data.

### Refresh token workflow

#### Prerequisites

Storing the refresh token on the client side is the only way to persist the session on something like a browser. However it has to been stored securely so there are two scenarios even here:

- The refresh token get stored in the browser in something like the localStorage or the sessionStorage (less secure)
- The refresh token is passed to the client using a HttpOnly cookie that are less reachable with Javascript.

#### Question

Assuming that we store the refresh token in an HttpOnly cookie I was wondering: does the endpoint `/refresh_token`, that returns a new JWT and a new refresh token, need to be authorized?

- If the endpoint has to be authorized, I should have a valid JWT for validating my user without requesting username and password again. In a scenario where the user uses the web application in a browser, then he closes it, then after a while he returns to the web application (and the JWT has expired) this is not possible and requires the user to authenticate again.
- If the endpoint is not authorized I cannot have, while validating the refresh token, a valid user instance to check the refresh token data against. So, the only thing that I can check is the validity of the refresh token with the store (or with JWT strategies). This solves the above-mentioned scenario but, is this safe enough?
- Another scenario is that the endpoint accepts also expired JWTs, validates them and then it checks the refresh token.

How should the refresh token be validated for a secure implementation? What are the best practices about this?